# Why can't simple_one_for_one specify different child id when call start_child?

Tags: erlang, child-process, erlang-supervisor

From the [doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html):

> Note that when the restart strategy is simple_one_for_one, the list of child specifications must be a list with one child specification only. (The child specification identifier is ignored.) No child process is then started during the initialization phase, but all children are assumed to be started dynamically using supervisor:start_child/2.

What's the design consideration for the part? It won't stop actively calling `register(<chid_id>, ChildPid)`
in each child process.

Comment: The spawned process can register itself, but the point of the simple_one_for_one is to create a legion of *identical* processes. You don't name worker threads in a pool in a language like C or Python -- you tend to simply keep references to them in a queue or pair of lists based on availability. Similarly, you don't tend to name workers spawned by a simple_one_for_one -- they are instead most commonly referenced directly by whatever other (non supervisor) process requested that they be spawned. They *can* register *themselves* but this is usually undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

Registering names for the PID of a child process is nothing to do with supervisor.

Consider a bog standard supervisor (not dynamic), the child specification provides the supervisor with enough information to start the child, typically by calling child_module:start_link, but it is the implementation of child_module:start_link that determines how a process is started and possibly name registration. A typical child_module:start_link implementation would be something like:

```
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, server_name}, ?MODULE, [], []).
```

It's this call to gen_server:start_link/4 that causes the registration of the resultant gen_server processes PID with a name of 'server_name'.

You could call gen_server:start_link/3 instead, in which case the gen_server process would have no name, unless you call erlang:register/2 in your init/1 behaviour implementation or something like that.

This is good because there's no reason to couple name registration with supervision, the name of a module/process is about that module and it's service, how it's accessed and used, not about supervision strategy.

It is quite common for supervised processes to register names for themselves, thus becoming named services that any other process can access easily.

For simple one to one supervision however, typically supervised children would not have names, because they should be homogeneous (i.e. don't create a simple one to one supervisor that starts various workers dynamically that all do different things, if they do different things then they almost certainly have different relative importance and they should be under different supervisors), and as such, unique names are not useful / appropriate.

The reason then that you can't choose a different child identifier when calling start_child, is that the child identifier is really the ID of the child specification (i.e. the type of child) not the ID of the child process in any way as such. Using a different child identifier would be saying 'this is a different type of process that does something different to the other one'. This fits with the requirement that the child specifications is a list of one.

Comment: What if I create the same type of children at different time but need differentiate them which one provide service for whom? Please refer to the detail for what I'm talking about in another question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923516/how-to-keep-track-of-children-processes-in-erlang)

Comment: I'm confused of the last paragraph you explained. Other type of children created with the child ID is because the behavior pattern do the job in the lower level.

Comment: Creating the same type at different times is fine. That's typical for a simple one for one. Differentiating them is fine too in my view, there must be many practical reasons this might be necessary, because those children must have been created for a reason, they may have state and be carrying out tasks relating to specific events relating to other processes, and I'm sure there are many legitimate cases giving rise to situations where they might need to be found/tracked. If it's always true that any one of the children crashing is no better/worse than any other, then that's as it should be.

Comment: I don't really understand your second comment, so I can only try rephrasing. Supervisor has no responsibility for naming child processes or providing/maintaining any unique identifier for each child. If I recall correctly, 'supervisor' keeps no unique ID at all for its children (other than the PID). Each child specification has a unique ID though (called the child ID). With non dynamic supervisors it seems like this is an ID for the child process itself, because there is only ever one process per ID, but really it's one ID per specification, and one child process per specification.